# An error occurred when running the spring cloud task batch app

Tags: initialization, exists, relation, spring-cloud-task

An error occurred when running the spring cloud task batch app

ERROR : Statement.execute(CREATE TABLE TASK_EXECUTION (...) FAILED!
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: exceptioin: "task_execution" A relation of names already exists

Is there a way to disable the table creation script?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPFtZ.png)

It would be nice to diverge whether to run ddl script (create table...) with the value in the local setting in that function...

ex. setting in spring batch app

- spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema=never

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCvNQ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04uuD.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zdeh.png)

Can I edit this source?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the database initialization of Spring Cloud Task by setting the property:

```
spring.cloud.task.initialize-enabled=false
```

It works similarly to `spring.batch.jdbc.initialize-schema`.

You can find more information on this in the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/docs/current/reference/html/#features-table-initialization).

Comment: I want to buy you a cup of coffee from the kind you who answered.
Thank you very much, senior.

Comment: Great to hear that the answer helped! Please accept the answer if it answered your question.